# error AngularJs:Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

Hey i'm new  in angularJs , i'm using service provider for my application , but i got this error: Unknown provider: MathServiceProvider <- MathService <- Monservice

here is my code :

```
 <div ng-controller="myController">
 Enter a number:
    <input type="number" ng-model="num" />
    <button ng-click="doSquare()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
    <button ng-click="doCube()">X<sup>3</sup></button>

    Answer: {{answer}}
 </div>
```

and my Js file is

```
  var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
  app.service('Mathservice',function()
        {
 this.add=function(a,b)
{
return a+b;
}
this.multiplication=function(a,b)
{
return a*b;
}
 this.devise=function(a,b)
{
return a/c;
}
this.Soustraction=function(a,b)
{
return a-c;
}
}
       );
app.service('Monservice', function(MathService){

this.s = function(a) { return Mathservice.multiplication(a,a); };
this.c = function(a) {
return Mathservice.multiplication(a,Mathservice.multiplication(a,a)); };

});

app.controller('myController', function($scope, Monservice) {

$scope.doSquare = function() {
    $scope.answer = Monservice.s($scope.num);
}

$scope.doCube = function() {
    $scope.answer = Monservice.c($scope.num);
}
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `Mathservice != MathService`. Be consistent in the way you spell that service name. And please, indent your code.

Comment: i thought MathService is a service that i should create by myself noo ??

Comment: Yes, so? Sometimes you name it MathService, and sometimes you name it Mathservice. JavaScript is case sensitive. Always name it MathService.

Comment: yes i understand it thank you !! :)